# is there a place to create a custom NavigationBar as a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I would like to create a custom **NavigationBar**(not sure if that's **NavigationBar** or **NavigationController**) using **UIView** Class to create a custom one, now I'm not sure what is the name of it and if it's possible :)
Here's a picture of what I talk about - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Nea.jpg)

Comment: No need to create a custom navigation bar to achieve the attached image. You just need to set the title and add the rightNavigationBarButton.

Comment: @Surjeet I do that cause i've got a problem with the Navigation bar across my app, the problem is every navigation background is blue so thats why i create a custom one.

Comment: Just create a custom `NavigationController`, with custom color for navigationBar, fonts, etc, and use it across your app. You will have a lot of trouble with a custom view.

Comment: @vpoltave ye but the thing is im trying to place it instead of the blue navigationController and dont know how to do that